# Fastest way to access data in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have an xml file with a list of 10k abbreviations and their full terms. I would like to store this xml into a structure in load time. Then will have a page of abbreviations that will constantly hit that structure to convert to the full term. In other word, one creation at the load time and many lookups. I am not sure what is the best structure I can use in terms of speed and reliance? For example should I use CoreData or NSDictionary, some other hash table? Should I just have the parser parse the NSXML for every term lookup?

Thanks, 
Ross

Comment: Where do you want the performance increase? At load time or just in terms of accessing the data?  Does how much memory you are using make a difference?

Comment: Are you sure it's going to be too slow?   My first suggestion would be to use NSDictionary and if that's too slow to consider another solution.  NSDictionary is actually surprisingly fast, key access is hashed, etc.   Try this, and then profile it.  If that's a bottleneck, then start looking at some more sophisticated structures, like P-Trees (but I'm guessing that's way overkill for this).

Answer (score 0):

Before anyone here can recommend any type of performance increases, you need to share two **critically important** pieces of information:

1. What are the details of your current implementation?
2. What is the specific [set of] performance bottleneck[s] that you are trying to address?

Without that, any subsequent discussion is no better than armchair quarterbacking during the superbowl;  a mildly amusing means of wasting time.